# Run function every x seconds - dearpygui

Tags: python, dearpygui

I have a window application in which I am trying to refresh a table every x seconds after running my function. However I could not find any suitable method to rerun the function within the event loop of the app. This is my code and the function I'm trying to rerun is FLAS(I'm returning a list of objects).

```
flights = FLAS()

with dpg.window(width=785, height=600, no_collapse=True, no_move=True, no_title_bar=True, no_resize=True):
    with dpg.table(header_row=True, policy=dpg.mvTable_SizingFixedFit, row_background=True, reorderable=True,
                resizable=False, no_host_extendX=False, hideable=True,
                borders_innerV=True, delay_search=True, borders_outerV=True, borders_innerH=True,
                borders_outerH=True):
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Callsign", width_fixed=True)
        dpg.add_table_column(label="FIX", width_fixed=True)
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Exit FIR", width_fixed=True)
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Next FIR", width_fixed=True)
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Entry FL", width_fixed=True)
        dpg.add_table_column(label="Exit FL", width_fixed=True)
        
        print(len(flights))
        if len(flights) == 0:
            flights.append(Flight("No flights in range", 000000, "XXX", 0, "XXXX", "XXXX",0,0,0,0))
        for flight in flights:
            with dpg.table_row():
                dpg.add_text(flight.callsign)
                dpg.add_text(flight.fix)
                dpg.add_text(flight.cFIR)
                dpg.add_text(flight.xFIR)
                dpg.add_text(flight.efl)
                dpg.add_text(flight.xfl)        
dpg.show_viewport()
dpg.start_dearpygui()
dpg.destroy_context()
```

Comment: Have you tried `while` loop?

Comment: @HanzTura I did, however I couldn't get it to work with a while loop because the while loop won't run dpg.start_dearpygui

Comment: Hmmm I'm not pretty familiar with dearpygui myself but you should be able to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can easy do it within the render loop:

https://dearpygui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/documentation/render-loop.html

The only thing you need now is to define a timer class.

The otherway would be to work with the Thread module.

DPG is not that popular so far, to ask on Stackoverflow. A better source to ask is on github or on the DPG Discord Server ( you will find some examples in the #support channel how to build a timer class and how to use it.